# How can I cast to Int an object from userInfo notification?

Tags: swift, casting

I am trying to parse `gcm.notification.createdAt` key, but its value is not being casted as `Int`.
Strangely it is not working even though the value type is clearly `Int` as you can see.
Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

```
userInfo is [AnyHashable("gcm.notification.chatUID"): -LgHYXKFNmP-mQo7s9nB, 
             AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): chat, 
             AnyHashable("gcm.notification.createdAt"): 1559389303, 
             AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, 
             AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1559389316529351%e413fc3ee413fc3e, 
             AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "You have a new message";
        title = "New Message from Lehz Raus";
    };
    badge = 1;
    sound = default;
}]

let userInfo =  response.notification.request.content.userInfo

guard let createdAt = userInfo["gcm.notification.createdAt"] as? Int else {
            print("gcm.notification.createdAt is not showing")
            return
           }

 //this works as expected
    guard let chatUUUUID = userInfo["gcm.notification.chatUID"] as? String else {
        print("no chatUUUUID printed")
        return
    }
```

Comment: What does `print(type(of: userInfo["gcm.notification.createdAt"]))` print?

Comment: Try `userInfo[AnyHashable("gcm.notification.createdAt")]`

Comment: @vacawama it prints `Optional<Any>
(lldb)`

Comment: Ok, unwrap it: what does `print(type(of: userInfo["gcm.notification.createdAt"]!))` print?

Comment: @vacawama ` __NSCFString
(lldb) `  It looks like it converted in String when sending it from the server. I have no idea why because I have tripled checked and on the server it is sent as Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your value is not really an `Int`.

You can investigate the underlying type by printing:

```
print(type(of: userInfo["gcm.notification.createdAt"]!))
```

From the comments, you said it returned: `__NSCFString` so the server is giving you a `String`.  You can convert that to an `Int` with an additional line in your `guard` statement:

```
guard let createdAt = userInfo["gcm.notification.createdAt"] as? String,
      let createdAtInt = Int(createdAt) else {
    print("gcm.notification.createdAt is not showing")
    return
}
```